# Wordpress single-product redirect by htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a theme with woocommerce and I want to rewrite even single product link.
Here is my htaccess file :

```
# BEGIN WordPress                                                                                                        
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>                                                                                                 
RewriteEngine On                                                                                                         
RewriteBase /                                                                                                            
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]                                                                                           
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f                                                                                      
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d                                                                                      
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]                                                                                             
RewriteRule ^formations/([A-Za-z0-9_]+) /construction-de-la-formation-en-cours/ [R=301]                                  
</IfModule>                                                                                                              

# END WordPress
```

I added myslef the line

```
RewriteRule ^formations/([A-Za-z0-9_]+) /construction-de-la-formation-en-cours/ [R=301]
```

To rewrite http://domain.com/formations/product-name/ to http://domain.com/construction-de-la-formation-en-cours/

But it doesn't work.

Comment: You need to do such stuff before the default WP routing, not after it.

Comment: You means after the line RewriteEngine On ?